# Copying vimrc does not work -- plugins don't install and only throws errors

Tags: vimrc

I watched tons of vim setup videos, for example [this is last one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0Bimr1079A) and this person claims it takes 10 seconds to setup vim anywhere. He just opens [vimrc file](https://gist.github.com/miguelgrinberg/527bb5a400791f89b3c4da4bd61222e4) and it immediately installs all the plugins (time 9:09). When I open this vimrc file I just get bunch of errors, nothing gets installed.
How do I make it work?
What is the secret?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: if you restart vim (assuming on the first start vim-plug is downloaded and installed) and do `:PlugInstall`, would it install plugins needed?

Comment: I remember I had this problem when I used vim-plug. I ended up using 2-step approach: 1) on the first start install vim-plug as in mentioned vimrc, message to "restart vim  and do `:PlugInstall`" then call `:finish` to stop loading vimrc. 2) restart vim and do what was messaged in 1)

Comment: and pls link you vimrc too

Answer (score 0):

The `Unknown function: plug#begin` error seems to indicate that vim-plug wasn't properly installed.

You can follow the instructions in here to install it:

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#installation

In particular, you should have a file named `~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim` in your system after you install it successfully. If you do have that file, then Vim should be able to find the `plug#begin` function when it's called from your vimrc.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the linked vimrc *tries* to download that file using `curl`. Maybe there's an error above the ones you pasted. Or maybe not, since it might have been silenced... Do you have `curl` available on your machine? That might explain why that part fails...

Comment: Hi, yes I have both ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim and curl... so I have no idea what is the reason

Comment: @YohanRoth Does your vimrc actually match the one from that link? It's complaining about `plug#begin` from line 2, but the linked vimrc has that call on line 10...

Comment: Please post output of `vim --version`, please [edit] your question to do so. Include the actual contents of your vimrc. Can you show inside your `~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim` a few lines, make sure there's a `plug#begin` function defined in there as expected?